# phpmailer not collecting data from form

Tags: php, phpmailer

There are a lot of posts on here saying the same thing that I am, and I have tried all the fixes that were posted for them, and none of them have worked. So I am at a complete loss.

I have the form on the html page, going to contact.php, but for the life of me I can't get it to pull any data through. I've been playing with this for several hours and have not been able to figure it out.

I have tried if empty and isset, and nothing is working, and the from is also showing as Root User when the email does come through, empty of course. So I don't know what to do, I thank everyone in advance for helping me figure this out.

**HTML Form:**

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="contact.php" >
   <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" spellcheck="false" 
      placeholder="Name*">
   <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="" spellcheck="false" 
      placeholder="Email*">
   <input type="text" id="phone" name="phone" value="" spellcheck="false" 
      placeholder="Phone*">
   <select name="bustype" size="1" id="bustype">
      <option selected>Type Of Business*</option>
      <option value="retailer">Retailer</option>
      <option value="wholsaler">Wholsaler</option>
      <option value="distributor">Distributor</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" id="units" name="units" value="" spellcheck="false" 
      placeholder="# of Units per Month*">
   <input type="text" id="locations" name="locations" value="" 
      spellcheck="false" placeholder="# of Locations*">
   <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="4" cols="44" spellcheck="false" 
      placeholder="Message*"></textarea>
   <input type="submit" id="Button2" name="submit" value="CONTACT US">
</form>
```

**php mailer**

```
<?php

$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$phone = $_REQUEST['phone'] ;
$bustype = $_REQUEST['bustype'] ;
$units = $_REQUEST['units'] ;
$locations = $_REQUEST['locations'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;


require("../PHPMailer_5.2.0/class.phpmailer.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();


$mail->Host = "mail.mydomain.com";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;


$mail->Username = "me@mydomain.com";
$mail->Password = "password";


$mail->From = $email;


$mail->AddAddress("me@someone.com");


$mail->WordWrap = 50;

$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = "Web Form Contact";

$mail->Body = '
<html>
<strong>Name:</strong> '.$name.'<br>
<strong>Email:</strong> '.$email.'<br>
<strong>Phone:</strong> '.$phone.'<br>
<strong>Business Type:</strong> '.$bustype.'<br>
<strong># of Units:</strong> '.$units.'<br>
<strong># of Locations:</strong> '.$locations.'<br>
<strong>Comments:</strong> '.$message.'<br>
</html>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Message could not be sent. <p>";
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
exit;
}

echo "Message has been sent";
?>
```

Comment: print_r($_REQUEST) and see what you're getting

Comment: Nothing is a working is a little vague.  Can you be more explicit?  What did you try, what happened?

Comment: I've tried     if(!empty($_POST['form_field']) && isset($_POST['form_field'])) for all the form fields and no data was being sent through, I've tried just if(!empty and still the same thing, email would only come through from Root User and no form data

Comment: Why are you using such an ancient version of PHPMailer? You have to put quite a bit of effort in to find a version that old! Checking basics like that should be the first thing you do. That said, it doesn't look like it's the problem here. You're forging the From address. Don't do that. Look at the contact form example provided with PHPMailer.

Comment: Thats the version my host provided, I'll go get the newest one, Thanks for that

Comment: Thank you @Synchro. I have fixed that, but am still getting empty emails

Comment: I download and installed 5.2.24 on my server, now I am getting connection issues

Answer (score 0):

Replace the $_REQUEST with $_POST like this

```
$email = $_POST['email'] ;
$name = $_POST['name'] ;
$phone = $_POST['phone'] ;
$bustype = $_POST['bustype'] ;
$units = $_POST['units'] ;
$locations = $_POST['locations'] ;
$message = $_POST['message'] ;
```

2. close the form with closing tag `</form>`

Comment: thanks for the closing tag on the form, it's in the html document locally, I just cut the code to paste here in front of that by accident, so thank you for the correction.

I changed from $_REQUEST to $_POST and I am still not getting any data from the form sent through, the email comes through with just this

Name: 
Email: 
Phone: 
Business Type: 
# of Units: 
# of Locations: 
Comments:

Comment: When you want POST data, you should use POST, however, the same data that is in $_POST is also in $_REQUEST because a POST is a request.  So if you are stating that the problem is that $_REQUEST was used instead of $_POST, that is incorrect.

Comment: I have an ssl on that domain, would that make any difference? do I need to include this `$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';`

Comment: Nevermind, I tried the ssl line with the correct port, and still got an empty email

Comment: I have switched from using smtp, I have changed to this

Comment: I have switched from using smtp, just using the mail.phps sample that phpmailer gives with 5.2.24, I have made the necessary changes to the file and still, mail goes through, but no form data is being sent through. I am at an absolute loss

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. When I reverted back to my original html form, I had left the `enctype="text/plain"` in the form tag, and didn't realize it. I'm so stupid. Once i removed that, everything was working fine.